# Selecting random ROUND number without being non-even distribution

Tags: javascript, random, distribution

So I want to make a number selector in JS that select a ROUND number between 1 and 100. Like selecting a winning ticket for example.

I found out I could use a function and then Math.round, like this

```
    function sort(min,max) {
    return Math.round(Math.randon() * (max - min) + min)
}
console.log(sort(1,100))
```

But then I readed Math.round will make a non-even distribution, with max and min values less likely to roll than the others.

So how can I solve this one? Getting a ROUND number between 1 and 100 with even distribution?

Comment: Why do you want to use round()?  floor or ceil might be better candidates.

Comment: I don't. I just need a round number. I just don't know how to round the number without `Math.round()` and in an even distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort is not a good name for random number picker. Anyway, looks pretty even to me (if you use floor)

```js
function rand_int(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
var bucket = {}
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  var x = rand_int(1, 10)
  bucket[x] = (bucket[x] || 0) + 1
}

console.log(bucket)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That +1 is for compesating the floor rounding the number down, isn' it?  Also, I didn't quite get the loop part. 100000 numbers?

Comment: The loop is for counting frequencies of each number 1-10 among million trials

Comment: Just so I can learn more... could I use `Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min - 1) + min)`?

Comment: Use my code to check it. I think it will bring numbers from 2-11